# Access Firebase Storage from Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

My ultimate target is to generate a pdf and send it via email through Firebase Cloud Function but I'm still testing things out. I am sending emails using Nodemailer. My next step is to include an image I have store in the same project on Firebase Storage.

How can I access the files I have in Storage to include as an attachment? My trigger for the function is `onCreate()` for a node in RTDB.

```
functions.database
    .ref("/jobs/draft/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot: any, context: any) => {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "access the files you have in Storage" you have to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage), as follows:

```
 //.....
  const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 //.....

  functions.database
      .ref("/jobs/draft/{id}")
      .onCreate((snapshot: any, context: any) => {

        const fileBucket = 'gs://bucket.appspot.com';
        const filePath = 'path/to/file';

        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
        const file = bucket.file(filePath);

        //.....

      });
```

See also https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html

Comment: The filePath should be a string with the path of the file needed but what should fileBucket be?

Comment: I seem to have trouble attaching the file to an email with nodemailer. `const file = bucket.file(filePath);` is an object about the file.

Comment: You may have a look at the doc for `File`: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html

Comment: Thank for your help @Renaud Tarnec. I' very close. I am getting the attached file in the email but it is empty. The path is correct because I am also getting the metadata of the same file and that is being retrieved correctly. I am using `file.get()`

Comment: solved: change the attachment > file to attachement > content

attachments: [{
     filename: 'image',
     contentType: contentType,
     content: attachment
    }],